# Handling multipart uploads

Tags: suave

I am trying to implement file upload using Suave and I'm failing to get it working. What I am doing is a multipart form post and I can find the file in ctx.request.files.[0]. However trying to read the tempFilePath using Read permission I get a sharing violation. When done the file has size 0. Am I supposed to access it through a stream somewhere else?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?